# 2014 Jeep SRT 6.4L oil filter was too small - what kind of damage?

Tags: engine, oil, engine-theory, jeep, oil-filter

What possible damage could my engine incur from having an oil filter installed that is smaller than the suggested size?  I have damage but I’m interested to hear what this forum has to say about it before I confirm my issue.  Please help.

Comment: When you say too small what do you mean? Are you saying that the filter body wasn't big enough for the oil or the connections didn't match?

Comment: An the threads matched but the physical size of the oil filter is much smaller.  Company website shows an appropriate size for a Jeep Patriot or compass.

Comment: What makes you think you have damage from that? How long did you run with the wrong oil filter?

Comment: A smaller oil filter will not damage the engine, if it replaced on the normal schedule, My 2017 car has a filter as small as a lawn tractor, size does not matter if oil changes are done on a regular basis.

Answer (score 0):

I had buddies back in Highschool that worked at a lube shop.  One story was that someone put the wrong size oil filter on a car and the oil filter blew off of the block.  Luckily, the car was shut down before catastrophic failure.

Don't ask me exactly how, as you would assume that there would be other issues that would attribute to it, and you would figure that an oil pump relief valve would have kept it from happening.  I never heard more, beyond that they put the right size on and the car ran fine.

Take it for the grain of salt, but just a thought.

Answer (score 0):

What would be more important is was the ABV, if necessary for your engine was present?

What bypass pressure you had vs what you required?

Granted you want as much surface as possible, but the other factors aren't going to be simply time-based issues as the filter media is.

Micron Filtration Beta, albeit to a much less extent as almost no one pays any attention to that.

Those are the issues that you would want to be concerned about, rather than simply size.